# Messages via SOAP throws CommunicationException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, distributed

This is how my service is set up:

```
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ChatCommunicationService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IChatService), new WSHttpBinding(), "Soap");
myServiceHost.Open();
```

This is how my webservice client is set up:

```
ChannelFactory<IChatService> scf = new ChannelFactory<IChatService>(new WSHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8080/Soap");
_chatService = scf.CreateChannel();
```

But when I am using it in my application I get an `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException`. I have tried for a long time and I have know idea how to solve it. Googling it shows something about setting keepalive to false but I dont know where to set it.

Note: It works in the beginning(I can send message via SOAP) but it always throws an exception at the same place. Talking directly to my database I get no exceptions. I have to use SOAP.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help :)

Error message:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userReA first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
trievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the exception it looks like your service is closing the underlying connection during processing.  Can you verify that your service is still running at the point that the request takes place in the client.

At the worst add some Console.WriteLine messages logging start and stop of the service.

Comment: The two first call to the service is okay. The rest after that is not.